# what is the best way to implement the generic action of controller where different response generated based on the params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

Below code are written in the controller action where we are generating a different action based on the action parameter and secondary we are only generating the xml response on the basis of different action parameters.It's not necessary that every case of action consist result tag as parent.It's vary between action to action.

```
doc = EncodeDecode.decode(request.raw_post)
action =  parse_xml(doc/'action')  if (doc/'action').first

#    action = 'fetch_thread_colors'
case action
when 'create_customer_profile'
  result = Customer::CustomerCrud.create_customer_profile(doc)
  render :xml => "<result>#{result}</result>"

when 'create_customer_payment_profile' 
  result = Customer::CustomerCrud.create_customer_payment_profile(doc)
  render :xml => "<result>#{result}</result>"
```

How we can achieve the best way to implement because My problem is that it's to big in term of line of codes I am having more than 300-350 cases in the switch block.Is there any way something I can achieve it using metaprogramming But we also need to consider the point for memory efficient.

Solutions should be efficient ,clean and optimized to implement.

Any object oriented approach also can help me out.

Comment: Please elaborate on the requirements and add more examples to your question. It is very frustrated to write an answer and then get told that the answer cannot handle unknown edge cases. Nobody will be able to help you when you do not add all important details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
module Customer
  class Result
    def initialize(result)
      @result = result
    end

    def to_xml
      "#{@result}"
    end
  end

  class WrappedResult < Result
    def to_xml
      "<result>#{@result}</result>"
    end
  end

  class CreateCrud
    def self.create_profile(doc)
      WrappedResult.new(true)
    end

    def self.create_payment_profile(doc)
      Result.new(false)
    end
  end

  class UpdateCrud
    def self.update_profile(doc)
      WrappedResult.new(true)
    end
  end
end

# in your controller
def render_view(result)
  "template xml"
end

def method_for_action(action_string)
  @actions ||= {
    "create_customer_profile" => Customer::CreateCrud.method(:create_profile),
    "create_customer_payment_profile" => Customer::CreateCrud.method(:create_payment_profile),
    "update_customer_profile" => Customer::UpdateCrud.method(:update_profile),
    "defaultacctcategory" => Proc.new do |doc|
      # do stuff
      Customer::Result.new(render_view(doc))
    end
  }

  @actions[action_string]
end
```

and then use it like

```
method_for_action("create_customer_payment_profile").call(doc).to_xml
#=> "false"
method_for_action("create_customer_profile").call(doc).to_xml 
#=> "<result>true</result>"
method_for_action("update_customer_profile").call(doc).to_xml
#=> "<result>true</result>"
method_for_action("defaultacctcategory").call(doc).to_xml
#=> "template xml"

doc = EncodeDecode.decode(request.raw_post)
action =  parse_xml(doc/'action')  if (doc/'action').first

result = method_for_action("defaultacctcategory").call(doc)
render xml: result
```

This allows you to protect any public but non-public facing methods in the class by whitelisting what can be called. It then wraps the result in an instance of `Result` or `WrappedResult` on a method by method case, depending on if you need the wrapping `<result>` tag. Downside is that you're now wrapping your result in a new object (if it wasn't a class already) which has `to_xml`, so if you have any code that was relying on it being anything else you'd have to update and adjust.

Comment: I am little bit confused ... your code can help me out or not so can you please help me how i can assume integrate it if action is just like below where there is no result tag of xml and all

Comment: when 'defaultacctcategory'
      gl_account = GeneralLedger::GlAccount.find_by_trans_flag_and_acct_flag('A','T')
      acc_category = GeneralLedger::GlCategory.find_all_by_id(gl_account.gl_category_id)
      render_view( acc_category,'gl_category','L')

Comment: @TusharPal So this method sometimes doesn't render XML at all? Or does render_view render XML via some other means?

Comment: it's rendering xml but using the template which we are calling render_view

Comment: There is no `render_view` in your question.

Comment: @TusharPal updated with a way of handling a controller method `render_view` if it returns a string or something. Not sure what exactly `render_view` is doing, but you could always add more `Result` subclasses and do special handling for "if it's this type of result class, we need to actually render a view instead of `render :xml`"